# Looking for a fast portable method for colorkeying 8bit images

Tags: c, image, transparency, blit

I am looking for a fast, C language, portable method (freestanding, no libraries) for performing colorkeyed blits. The target is a freestanding emulator library for a retro style computer design.

My current take on this (the images are stored in `uint32_t` typed storage, however they are 8bit palettized images):

```
uint32_t sdata; /* Last read source data (4 pixels) */
uint32_t ckey;  /* Prepared colorkey, such as 0x30303030U if the key is 0x30 */
uint32_t t32;

...

t32 = sdata ^ ckey; /* 0x00 where the colorkey matches */
t32 = (((t32 & 0x7F7F7F7FU) + 0x7F7F7F7FU) | t32) & 0x80808080U;
t32 = (t32 - (t32 >> 7)) + t32; /* Colorkey mask prepared (0xFF or 0x00) */
```

Some explanations:

It basically utilizes [this bit twiddling hack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) modified to produce a mask to be applied on the source. The second line is the core of the hack, which my case returns 0x80 for every pixel (byte) not matching the colorkey, 0 otherwise. The third line just expands all 0x80's to 0xFF's. Later applying the mask is trivial, so I didn't include it (and in the actual code it is combined with other stuff, anyway).

So the question is, under the constraints of plain vanilla C (C89, to be precise), is there any way to make this task faster in general (for most architectures)?

Comment: You might get better traction on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I don't need the solution to be like mine, I just put it up for reference that yes, I was working on it, and got here. Any faster solution I believe would require some different approach, so I rather hope someone throws in some neat own idea rather than messing with mine.